# meteorJS sessions using collections

Tags: session, meteor, collections

Is it possible to combine **MeteorJS** collections and sessions?  I can't find any information about it.

```
Template.search.helpers({
  transToEnT: function(){
   var try = TransToEnT.find();
  Session.set('mySession', try);
  var sessionDataToLog = Session.get('mySession');
  return sessionDataToLog;
  }
});
```

this is my attempt. Unfortunately, unsuccessful.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Some explanation of your goal would be helpful

Comment: Try `TransToEnT.find().fetch()` instead of `.find()`, so that you store the actual array and not the cursor.

Comment: `.find()` returns a *cursor* which is a *function*. `Session` can't store functions.

Comment: This collection gets some generated data and prints it out after user submits. I'm having a problem when two users are online and one of them click's the submit button and the other get's unexpected page refresh with new content. So, I'm trying to solve this issue using sessions. Unfortunately, TransToEnT.find().fetch() didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to distinguish different user, it is better to use meteor original user and account ([Meteor user and account](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html)) rather than manipulating session.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor sessions and collections are different. 
Collections are basically database, by default it's mongodb. AND sessions are the state of data-source for a particular client.

> In meteor, if you want to apply reactivity of one component to other
>   component then we use sessions. **Example**: On change of one facet if you want to update other facet and reset data-source to the view, we can use Sessions and return session from the helper function of the template.

If you want to distinguish between users data. Use pub and sub for different users. Don't subscribe all the data for a user. Use Dynamic pub and sub.

Only user specific data should present for a particular user/client.